# Defining different forms of argparse argument inputs

Tags: python, argparse

I have just started out in using `argparse`, my code works but I am trying to parse in different values as to how the user types in the argument.

Currently this is my code:

```
def setup_args():
    """
    Set up args for the tool
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=("Get all file versions of a status in a project"),
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

    # Positional Arguments
    parser.add_argument('project',
                        type=str,
                        help='Name of the to look into')

    parser.add_argument('status',
                        type=str,
                        help='Define which status to look into')

    # Optional Arguments
    parser.add_argument('-o',
                        '--output',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='Write to output to text file if used')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = setup_args()

    # Check the status set
    status_list = ['Pending', 'Work in Progress', 'Approved', 'Rejected']
    if not args.status in site_list:
        raise ValueError("Please input one of the status : 'Pending', 'Work in Progress', 'Approved', 'Rejected'")

    output_query(args.project, status, args.client, args.output)
```

As you can see in my `main`.. It only register those case-sensitive status names that I have defined.
Are there any ways in which I can also make my code to register if they are typed in small caps - `'pending', 'work in progress', 'approved', 'rejected'` or in short forms - `'p', 'wip', 'a', 'r'`?

One of the way I can implement is using `if..elif..`

```
if args.client == ('pending' or 'p'):
    args.client = 'Pending'
elif args.client == ('work in progress' or 'wip'):
    args.client = 'Work in Progress'
elif args.client == ('approved' or 'a'):
    args.client = 'Approved'
elif args.client == ('rejected' or 'r'):
    args.client = 'Rejected'
```

Though it works, it looks a bit 'long-winded' to me. If I have multiple arguments, this would means I will need to put in a lot of `if...elif...` which may not be practical unless this is the only way.
Is there a better solution to get around this?

EDIT:

This is how I have been running my command : `python prog.py my_project Pending`
but I am thinking of scenarios where one could type it this way : `python prog.py my_project pending` or `python prog.py my_project p`, notice that the caps P has become small letter..

Comment: That's essentially how the output argument you have works, right? Can you just do it like that? put the short name first then the long version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generalize the `status` check with `.lower()` and restricting the number of characters that you check.

For example, if I define an abbreviated list of 'choices', I can test anything that looks like the big names with:

```
In [239]: choices = ['pend', 'work', 'appr','reje']
In [240]: status_list = ['Pending', 'Work in Progress', 'Approved', 'Rejected']
In [241]: for wd in status_list:
     ...:     if wd.lower()[:4] in choices:
     ...:         print(wd)
     ...:         
Pending
Work in Progress
Approved
Rejected
```

You probably shouldn't expect your user to enter the full 'Work in Progress' string.  To do so would require quoting.  Otherwise the shell will break that into 3 strings.

A variation on this test uses `startswith`:

```
for wd in status_list:
     if any([wd.lower().startswith(n) for n in choices]):
         print(wd)
```

You could also let the parser do value checking

```
parser.add_argument('status',
                    # type=str,   # default, don't need to add it
                    choices = ['pending', 'work', 'approved', 'rejected'],
                    help='Define which status to look into')
```

That generates a nice error message if the string doesn't match.  And it incorporates the choices into the help.  Try it and see what happens.

The disadvantage is that it doesn't allow abbreviations or upper/lower case.  (A custom `type` function can get around those restrictions, but that's a more advanced technique).

==================

A way to use `type` is to define a little function:

```
def abrev(astr):
    return astr.lower()[:4]
```

which works in the above test:

```
for wd in status_list:
    if abrev(wd) in choices:
        print(wd)
```

In a parser it can be used as:

```
In [253]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [254]: p.add_argument('status', type=abrev, choices=choices);

In [255]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] {pend,work,appr,reje}

positional arguments:
  {pend,work,appr,reje}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

Sample calls:

```
In [256]: p.parse_args(['Work'])
Out[256]: Namespace(status='work')

In [257]: p.parse_args(['status'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] {pend,work,appr,reje}
ipython3: error: argument status: invalid choice: 'stat' (choose from 'pend', 'work', 'appr', 'reje')
...

In [258]: p.parse_args(['reject'])
Out[258]: Namespace(status='reje')

In [259]: p.parse_args(['Pending'])
Out[259]: Namespace(status='pend')
```

Comment: cool.. I had thought I can make it more versatile.. I guess I will need to think of some other ways to get around with it.. Else I will need to tell users to type in specific keywords

Comment: Dictionaries are another useful tool for mapping from one set of strings to other strings, or better yet other objects.

Comment: Okay, wasn't aware of using dictionary. Sounds like a viable option to use dictionary, rather than `if...elif...`

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tested it, looking at the `add_argument` function documentation, you should be able to add them as the first arguments to it.

> name or flags - Either a name or a list of option strings, e.g. foo or -f, --foo.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method

Comment: I have updated my thread with slightly more information.. correct me if I am wrong, but isn't `name or flags` where you type in the input, in my case I am focusing on name